# How do i change the keys of objects to use the key pair instead?

Tags: reactjs

Below is an object of an object. How do i convert the keys to use the id instead as the keys?

```
const data = {
    "0": {
        "id": 1912,
        "title": "Books",
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 1958,
        "title": "Brands",
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2037,
        "title": "Logo",
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 2038,
        "title": "Colour",
    },
}
```

How do i replace the keys to use the id instead such as below?

```
const data = {
    "1912": {
        "id": 1912,
        "title": "Banana",
    },
    "1958": {
        "id": 1958,
        "title": "Apple",
    },
    "2037": {
        "id": 2037,
        "title": "Orange",
    },
    "2038": {
        "id": 2038,
        "title": "Pineapple",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
We loop through the keys of the original object and access each of the ids through the object by `data[x].id`. Now, instead of explicitly grabbing the `id` like we did when we wanted to set the `key`, we just need to grab the remaining values by accessing `data[x]`.

```
let newObj = {}
Object.keys(data).map(x => {
    newObj[data[x].id] = data[x]
})

console.log(newObj)
```

By the way, just for reference, you have different `title` values in the second `Object` but I am assuming that was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic, non fancy way of doing it:

```
<html>
</html>

<script>
    const data = {
        "0": {
            "id": 1912,
            "title": "Books",
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 1958,
            "title": "Brands",
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 2037,
            "title": "Logo",
        },
        "3": {
            "id": 2038,
            "title": "Colour",
        },
    }
    console.log("before: ", data)
    let data1 = []

    for (var k in data) {
        var d = data[k];
        data[k]
        data1[d.id] = d
        console.log(d)
        console.log(data1)
    }
</script>
```

Having said that... you will end up with alot of empty objects in your array between those numbers!

Answer (score 0):

Create an array from values of data and reduce it into a single object.

```js
const data = {
  "0": {
      "id": 1912,
      "title": "Books",
  },
  "1": {
      "id": 1958,
      "title": "Brands",
  },
  "2": {
      "id": 2037,
      "title": "Logo",
  },
  "3": {
      "id": 2038,
      "title": "Colour",
  },
}

const result = Object.values(data).reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  acc[curr.id] = curr
  return acc
},{})

console.log(result)
```